# Low spread high power laser

Tags: laser, precision, high-power

I am looking for a laser which can travel about 10 km through air from one end of a lake to another.

It needs to have a minimal spread, i.e. a small diameter spread over the 10 km - less than 10 cm over this entire distance.

Does such a thing exist?
If not, what is achievable?

Comment: "what is achievable": Within which budget? Because clearly, optic prices scale very nonlinearly with size/precision, and you'll need large lenses or mirrors for narrow beams,  and they must be extremely accurately manufactured.

Comment: most likely it exists, but you would certainly need to consider safety issues for its use. If you are pointing it across a public space, how can you guarantee that some unfortunate will not wander into its path? You need to wear dark glasses even if you look for long at the spot these things project onto a piece of white paper.

Comment: @MarcusMüller roughly $10k

Comment: OK, which wavelength (this really might not be possible)? To be honest, this sounds like you want to do optical communications, is that right?

Comment: @MarcusMüller actually adjustable collimating lenses come on even fairly low cost (about 50$) lasers, powered at about 500mW. I have no idea what the maximum range is (I've played with them over about 10m) but you would want to exercise great caution before pointing them at head height in an open public space. Actually, you just should not do that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller it is for an experiment to measure the curvature of the earth over the lake surface. do you have a way to do this in detail?

Comment: @user813801 nice experiment! But would you *really* need only 10cm of beam diameter for that? Wouldn't it suffice if the intensity maximum was in the center of the beam? (also: curvature of earth *and* big body of water might indicate nonlinear medium air with temperature gradient and water vapor concentration, so I don't know how perfectly circular the resulting beam could be!)

Comment: I agree with @Marcus. Refraction of the light due to changes in air density may be a big problem.

Comment: @user813801 stupid question: wouldn't be looking 10km through a telescope be the same experiment, in its core?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, scintillation in the horrible optical path (above water) makes discussion of the laser's lens optical quality a moot point. You might expect a beam divergence of (very) roughly milliradian-per-kilometer - a path above water would likely be worse. And *on top of scintillation*, you'd likely have a temperature gradient where light path isn't a straight line. Scintillation *might* be averaged-out: a temperature gradient can't be averaged.

Answer (score 2):

One metre over 1km is about one milliradian (1 mrad). That is about as good as lasers get out of the box. You need 100 times better than that. The optics required are going to be very expensive. As a guess, think of using a telescope with a diameter of at least 20cm at the transmitter end. Calculations are [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-realistically-the-least-possible-beam-divergence-of-a-laser).

> The diffraction limited divergence angle is given by  θ=2.44λD  where
> λ  is the wavelength of the laser beam and D is the diameter of the
> exit pupil of the laser, assuming that it is circularly symmetric.
>
> So, the next question is, how big can you make D to get the the
> smallest divergence. Years ago, it was reported in Aviation Week and
> Space Technology that a space based laser might have a 4 meter
> telescope diameter. Assuming a wavelength of 1 micron, the full
> divergence angle is 671 nanoradians (0.138 arc seconds). Now that is
> the lower limit in space.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a HeNe laser? Compared to LEDs they are bulky, low power output and need a high voltage power supply. They do spread much less ,you can shine these at night making a red dot in the clouds. My old tubes got broken in the Christchurch earthquake, you could google surplus HeNe laser tubes. They did appear in old electronics mags in the 70s and 80s before the LEDs got more powerful.

Comment: how much does the dot spread over say 10km?

Answer (score 0):

Usually laser over such distance require specialized optics to be collimated.

Here are some of these optics:
https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=1379